# Log4j2 - PatternLayout dependend on LogLevel

Tags: log4j2

Is it possible to define two different PatternLayouts and dependend on the application LogLevel it uses the first or the second one?

Example:

If i run my application with ERROR Level, which is the default, it should print the log statements like:

```
$java -jar myApp.jar param1=value1

Error Message 1
Error Message 2
```

But if i run my application with INFO or DEBUG, it should print the log Statements like:

```
$java -jar myApp.jar --debug param1=value1

DEBUG | 18.03.2016 11:04:43,412 1058 | Debug Message 1
DEBUG | 18.03.2016 11:04:43,412 1058 | Debug Message 2
INFO  | 18.03.2016 11:04:43,414 1060 | Info Message 1
ERROR | 18.03.2016 11:04:43,420 1066 | Error Message 1
ERROR | 18.03.2016 11:04:43,420 1066 | Error Message 2
```

Internally if the parameter --debug or --info is given, my app is switching the global LogLevel. The default is ERROR.

How should i configure my [log4j2.xml](https://github.com/cecom/PACIFy/blob/develop/impl/src/main/resources/log4j2.xml) to accomplish this?? I could not find any solution. For reference my [commandLine parser](https://github.com/cecom/PACIFy/blob/develop/commandline/src/main/java/com/geewhiz/pacify/commandline/PacifyViaCommandline.java#L91) and the [util class](https://github.com/cecom/PACIFy/blob/develop/common/src/main/java/com/geewhiz/pacify/utils/LoggingUtils.java) where i switch the LogLevel at runtime.

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding what you mean by "run my application with ERROR level". To do that it implies you set a logger (the root logger?) to level ERROR. To then set it to debug you edited the file to reset the level to INFO or DEBUG, at which point you could also edit the pattern.  But let's suppose you use a system property to contain the level value.  If you do that you could use a pattern selector and select the pattern based on the system property.  If you are trying to do this some other way please let us know.

Comment: Please update the question to include the program code that should produce the results you mention.

Comment: I updated my question i hope it is better now.

Comment: I was hoping to see what your Java program looked like.

Comment: @RemkoPopma i added it? Look at the links.

Comment: Ah. Missed that. Okay, so depending on command line params you modify the log level of the logger in your main class. So that's where the "run my application with ERROR level" comes from. Ok let me try to answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the hint of @RemkoPopma i did some more research and found a solution. My log4j2.xml looks now like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout>
                <ScriptPatternSelector defaultPattern="%highlight{%-5p | %d{dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %r | %m%n}">
                    <Script name="selector" language="javascript"><![CDATA[
                       substitutor.replace("${main:pacifyLogLevel}");
                    ]]>
                    </Script>
                    <!-- INFO and DEBUG are using the defaultPattern -->
                    <PatternMatch key="ERROR" pattern="%-5p %m%n" />
                </ScriptPatternSelector>
            </PatternLayout>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="com.geewhiz.pacify" level="error" />
        <Root level="error">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

I also had to add the following line to my [Logging Util](https://github.com/cecom/PACIFy/blob/develop/common/src/main/java/com/geewhiz/pacify/utils/LoggingUtils.java) class, where i switch the LogLevel at runtime:

```
MainMapLookup.setMainArguments(new String[] { "pacifyLogLevel", level.toString() });
```

The result of

```
substitutor.replace("${main:pacifyLogLevel}");
```

is used and looked up in the PatternMatch. If not found he uses the defaultPattern. So in my application only the ERROR Level has a different LogPattern. The other ones are using the default log pattern.

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Pattern Selectors at the end of the PatternLayout documentation.

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout